# Class attribute becoming undefined after javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
class MyQueue {
    contructor() {
        this.inputStack = new MyStack();
        this.outputStack = new MyStack();
    }

    push(val) {
        this.inputStack.push(val);
    }

    pop() {
        if(this.outputStack.empty()) {
            const { inputStack, outputStack} = moveInputToOutput(
                this.inputStack,
                this.outputStack,
            );
            this.inputStack = inputStack;
            this.outputStack  = outputStack;
        }   
       return this.outputStack.pop();
    }

    peek() {
        if(this.outputStack.empty()) {
            const { inputStack, outputStack} = moveInputToOutput(
                this.inputStack,
                this.outputStack,
            );
            this.inputStack = inputStack;
            this.outputStack  = outputStack;
        }   
       return this.outputStack.top();
    }

    empty() {
        return this.inputStack.empty() && this.outputStack.empty();
    }

}

const moveInputToOutput = (inputStack, outputStack) => {
    while(!inputStack.empty()) {
        const inputvalue = inputStack.pop();
        outputStack.push(inputvalue);
    }
    return {
        inputStack,
        outputStack,
    };
 }


class MyStack {
    constructor() {
        this.first = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    push(value) {    
        const node = new Node(value);
        node.next = this.first;
        this.first = node;
        this.size++;
    }
    
    pop() {
        const node = this.first;
        this.first = this.first?.next ? this.first.next: null;
        this.size = this.size == 0 ? 0 : --this.size;
        return node?.value
    }
    
    empty() {
        return this.first === null;
    }

    top() {
        const node = this.first;
        return node?.value;
    }
}

class Node {
    constructor(value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Getting an error of

```
Line 9 in solution.js
        this.inputStack.push(val);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    Line 9: Char 25 in solution.js (MyQueue.push)
    Line 105: Char 26 in solution.js (helper_select_method)
    Line 169: Char 22 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 100: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

I am calling myQueue class to create an object to make the object, but when calling the push function from the stack class, it is making the this variable a undefined, trying to understand why, can anybody help me on this, looks like maybe a very minor issue, not able to find for hours

Comment: Hi. Try to isolate the error with debbuging  "const myStack = new MyStack();
myStack.push(1);
console.log(myStack.top()); // output 1" and "const myQueue = new MyQueue();
myQueue.push(1);
console.log(myQueue.pop()); // output 1"

Comment: this.inputStack.push(val); this is the place it is faling

Comment: const queue = new MyQueue();
queue.push(20);, but here only shows me this.inputStack as undefined

Comment: Why does `moveInputToOutput()` need to return the stacks if they're the same as the arguments?

Comment: yes could have made it a class help method, using the this, but it is failing before thath

Comment: Typo: `contructor` should be `constructor`. So you're never initializing the properties.

Comment: should have used a lint, I will make sure, from next time,it is a very silly mistake, thanks for the help